# How to edit my script to combine its outputs in one table per server from serverlist?

Tags: powershell

Could you please inform me how can I make my script to format its output in a single table for all "services" per "server"?

Please find my current PowerShell script below:

```
$serverList = gc computer.txt
$serviceList = gc service.txt

if ((Test-Path OUTPUT.txt) -eq $true) {
Write-Host "Deleting existing OUTPUT file"
Remove-Item OUTPUT.txt
}

ForEach ($server in $serverList)
{
    $style = @{Expression={$server};Label="Server Name";width=30}, `
    @{Expression={$_.Name};Label="Service Name";width=20}, `
    @{Expression={$_.StartMode};Label="StartMode";width=10}, `
    @{Expression={$_.State};Label="State";width=10}, `
    @{Expression={$_.ProcessId};Label="ProcessId";width=10}

Write-Host "Starting Service Check on $server"
    ForEach ($service in $serviceList)
    {
        Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $server -Filter "Name='$service'" | Select-Object -Property Name, StartMode, State, ProcessId | Format-Table $style | Out-File OUTPUT.txt -Append
    }
Write-Host "Service Check Completed on $server"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WMI appends the property PSComputername. You can just append it in your select-object-command like so:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $server -Filter "Name='$service'" | Select-Object -Property PScomputername, Name, StartMode, State, ProcessId | Format-Table $style | Out-File OUTPUT.txt -Append
```